# PHP !isset returns true when not set

Tags: php

Firstly, my code:

```
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT id FROM users WHERE
                                        username = :user_email OR
                                        email = :user_email");
        $user_email = $_POST["usernameemail"];
    $stmt->execute(array(
                                    'user_email'=>$user_email
                                    ));
    $account_exist = $stmt->fetch();
    if(!isset($account_exist)) {
        $account_exist_error = '<p style="color:#F00;">Username or Email not found</p>';
    }
```

$account_exist_error does not return when the query doesn't find anything

I have also tried

```
if($account_exist === '') {
    ect
}
```

Neither of these return anything, and other relevant questions are not helping me, $account_exist = '' is set earlier in my code

Comment: The title of your question describes normal behavior. Furthermore, `$stmt->fetch()` does return something...

Comment: `@Sneaky down voter`, please give a reason for down voting or you don't know why did you down vote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally, `empty($var_name)` would be more reliable, which will return true for anything `null`, blank, or undefined. This even includes empty arrays.

However, in this case, you are returning a DB object. Which will always return true for [isset](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php), and false for [empty](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php). So you are going to want to use the DB object API. In which case, you should use [rowCount](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php).

Comment: Should I use empty() when dealing with arrays?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php - full list of what empty() considers to be... empty.  For example, oolean FALSE, integer 0, empty strings (""), NULL, and arrays with no items are all empty.

Comment: I modified the answer to explain better

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
if(!$account_exist)
```

instead of

```
if(!isset($account_exist))
```

Because, it's return values are

```
TRUE    Success. Data has been fetched
FALSE   Error occurred
NULL    No more rows/data exists or data truncation occurred
```

In this case `false` and `null` both are falsy values and works with `!` operator. If you use

```
f(!isset($account_exist))
```

Then, it's is always set, because `$account_exist` contains a value.

Comment: Sneaky down voter, give a reason for down voting or you don't know why you down voted ?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
if ($account_exist == null)
```